# WebSocketException: Connection to url.. was not upgraded to websocket. It is working fine in angular but not in flutter why?

Tags: flutter, websocket

I have tried to do in 2 ways it's not working while it is working in angular

1. way

```
    var channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
      Uri.parse('wss://......./...../mywebsockets'),
      headers: {
        'Connection': 'Upgrade',
        'Upgrade': 'websocket'
       }
      );
    
    channel.stream.listen((event) { 
      print(event);
    });
```

2nd way

```
    StompClient client = StompClient(
    config: StompConfig.SockJS(
        url: 'https://....../.../mywebsockets',
        webSocketConnectHeaders: {
             
        'Upgrade': 'websocket',
         'Connection': 'Upgrade',
        },
        onConnect: (StompFrame connectFrame) {
          print('connected');
    
}, 
    onWebSocketError: (dynamic error) => print(error.toString()),
          onStompError: (d) => print("stomp error"),
          onDisconnect: (d)=> print("disconnect"),

    )
);
```

At backend(java) we removed .withSockJs() it is not working. Removed handshake still not working.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that WebSocket source code is actually ditching the WSS scheme and sending an HTTPS request with websocket headers.

```
uri = Uri(
    scheme: uri.isScheme("wss") ? "https" : "http",
    userInfo: uri.userInfo,
    host: uri.host,
    port: uri.port,
    path: uri.path,
    query: uri.query,
    fragment: uri.fragment);
```

Source: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/aa793715e0f122cbd27cd8f9cc12201ff43c19b1/sdk/lib/_http/websocket_impl.dart#L1014 .